# Using Map<Integer,Integer> by taking the input from a user

Tags: java, string, dictionary, hashmap, integer

I have a question about Maps, from the type Integer,Integer. I made a mistake by solving a problem based on `<Integer,Integer>` map on `<String,String>`, the end result was correct however, the order of numbers was not descending. That would be solved if I chose `Integer` instead of `String`s.

How can I take the input from the user and assign it to keys/values of my map when it is `Map<Integer, Integer>`? I used `substring()` and `indexOf()` to make my old map but for integers I couldn't find a way

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import type.lib.*;

public class MapTesting {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Map<String,String> normal = new HashMap<String,String>();
    output.println("Enter your map, one key-value pair per line,");
    output.println("comma-separated. Use empty line as sentinel.");

    for ( String entry = input.nextLine(); entry.length() !=0;
        entry = input.nextLine()) {
        int comma = entry.indexOf(",");
        String key = entry.substring(0,comma);
        String value = entry.substring(comma+1);
        normal.put(key,value);
    }
    output.println("The input map is:");
    output.println(normal);

    Map<String,String> reverse = new HashMap<String,String>();
    boolean distinct = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : normal.entrySet()) {
        String keyY = entry.getKey();
        String valueE = entry.getValue();
        String existingReverseValue = reverse.get(valueE);

        if (existingReverseValue != null) {
            int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(existingReverseValue);
            int potentialNewValue = Integer.parseInt(keyY);
            if ( potentialNewValue < currentValue) {
                reverse.put(valueE,keyY);
            }
        } else {
            reverse.put(valueE,keyY);
        }
    }
    output.println("The inverted map [using the smaller key as a tie breaker]:");
    output.println(reverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming these Strings are the correct representation you want from your input, something as simple as `int keyInt = Integer.valueOf(key)` will get the integer of the number represented by the String.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll i don't want to get the number represented by the string , i want to know if there is a way i can make this program with Map<Integer,Integer> using the same approach i did with strings.. to be more specific , how can i get the key/values from the user, as you can see i can easily do that by substring() and indexOf() i can locate what the user inputs..

Comment: All user input is read as `String` or per single `byte`. If you read `byte` by `byte`, then good luck. If you read `String` by `String`, then you will need to convert `String` into `Integer`, and use this `Integer` however you want/need, which in this case seems to be the key and value for your `Map`.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll that comment should be the answer.

Comment: @TJamesBoone 
God bless your soul, it works perfectly, i didn not know that i can locate using strings and then parse into integer .. that's too acvanced for me , but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps you want to take:

1. To move away from using `Map<String, String>` to `Map<Integer, Integer>`, you'll want to convert your input to an Integer *before*
   putting it in your map.
2. Next, you'll want to extend HashMap and override the `entrySet()`
   method to return the entry set sorted by keys descending.  This will
   also involve a custom implementation of the Comparator interface.

You can do this like so.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MapTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<Integer, Integer> normal = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        output.println("Enter your map, one key-value pair per line,");
        output.println("comma-separated. Use empty line as sentinel.");

        for ( String entry = input.nextLine(); entry.length() !=0;
              entry = input.nextLine()) {
            int comma = entry.indexOf(",");
            Integer key = Integer.parseInt(entry.substring(0,comma));
            Integer value = Integer.parseInt(entry.substring(comma+1));
            normal.put(key,value);
        }
        output.println("The input map is:");
        output.println(normal);

        // Here we make our reverse map an instance of our custom DescendingKeysMap.
        Map<Integer, Integer> reverse = new DescendingKeysMap();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : normal.entrySet()) {
            Integer keyY = entry.getKey();
            Integer valueE = entry.getValue();
            Integer existingReverseValue = reverse.get(valueE);

            if (existingReverseValue != null) {
                int currentValue = existingReverseValue;
                int potentialNewValue = keyY;
                if ( potentialNewValue < currentValue) {
                    reverse.put(valueE,keyY);
                }
            } else {
                reverse.put(valueE,keyY);
            }
        }
        output.println("The inverted map [using the smaller key as a tie breaker]:");
        output.println(reverse);
    }

    /**
     * Extends HashMap<Integer, Integer> and Overrides entrySet() to return the entries sorted by keys descending.
     */
    public static class DescendingKeysMap extends HashMap<Integer, Integer>{

        @Override
        public Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet() {
            List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(super.entrySet());
            // Sort
            Collections.sort(entries, new ByKeysDescending());
            return new LinkedHashSet<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>(entries);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> to compare by the keys descending.
     */
    public static class ByKeysDescending implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e2) {
            // return the opposite of comparing the keys, to get a descending order
            return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey()) * -1;
        }
    }
}
```